# Bespoke PHP Templating Engine

Tags: php, templates, template-engine

As a small part of a university project I'm working on (custom MVC based project management system), I need to develop a template engine. I don't wish to use an off the self system such as Smarty because I've written every other part of the project myself and don't want to go back on that now.

Anyway, I've managed to code something simple so far, I have a class, create an instance of it, add some data to the instance, then pass in a template file. The file has a series of tags like {this} when then get replaced with the data. Simple.

The issue I'm having is when it comes to looping things - i.e. a table of users or a list of categories. At the moment I have a template file for the page (users.html) which contains the opening and closing  tags, with a template tag between them called {users}. I then have another template file (users-detail.html) which displays a table row with the user info in. I'm creating a new instance of the users-detail.html template, adding the data, parsing it, then placing the output (string of HTML) into an array. I then loop this array, attach all the strings together, then assign this to the {users} tag in the users.html template file.

As you can probably tell from that explanation it is a bit of a bodge, and there are probably better methods out there for doing what I'm trying to achieve. Ideally I want to avoid using PHP in the template files if possible, and I often need to have multiple loops within one template file.

If anyone has any tips / advice on how I can achieve this, or any tutorials I could follow to get some inspiration that would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the source code for h2o templates - https://github.com/speedmax/h2o-php - should help you on your way

Comment: Why don't you look into the code of existing template engines that have what you're looking for and learn from it? What's better than a practical example?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that approach before (including another template for the insides of loops).  I used to work on an old version of [vbulletin](https://www.vbulletin.com/) which does (or did) this.  It makes things annoyingly complicated because you can't just add a loop to a template - without setting up a whole new template for each layer of looping.

I'd advise you instead to go along the route of [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Classically, this statement:

> I don't wish to use an off the self system such as Smarty because I've written every other part of the project myself and don't want to go back on that now.

... indicates you really should just be using Smarty.  In the real world that would be a poor justification for re-implementing something yourself.  But I am like you, and I understand that you want to implement something yourself (because you want to learn, you find it fun, you are a perfectionist, etc).  As long as you do it on your own time and it's a personal project, go for it.

It would be worth studying Smarty to see how it works (not just the syntax but how it compiles templates, stores the compiled version etc).  Are you comfortable writing a tokeniser/parser in PHP which can compile your template language and output PHP?  If you are advanced enough to do it, do it.  At the very simplest, you read in a tag like `{foreach from=$something}` and somehow translate it to `<?php foreach ($something as $thing) { ?>`.  You check token types, etc to make sure the template tag is valid, and so on.